# Sending a PIL image through Python requests

Tags: python, image, python-requests, save, python-imaging-library

I have a requirement to create an image and save it in a database. I am creating it with python Pillow and saving it as JPEG.

```
image = Process().mandelbrot(width, height, max_iter)

mem_file = BytesIO()
image.save(mem_file, "JPEG", quality=100)
mem_file.seek(0)
```

After the creation, I am trying to save it in the database via python-requests

```
form_data = {'image': ('mandelbrot'+str(uuid.uuid4().hex), mem_file)}
requests.post(url='http://database:5000/images', files=form_data)
```

I am trying to send a form-data request but when I check the data that comes to my database the file is not found and its value is None

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('image', <FileStorage: 'mandelbrot8a9275e838a04a0f94b731c47bc6bdd4' (None)>)])
```

Does anyone know how can I send a PIL file throw a python request using form-data mimetype without getting a file with None value?

Comment: Please try with this modification: `form_data = {'image': ('mandelbrot'+str(uuid.uuid4().hex), mem_file.getvalue())}`

Comment: You're doing it right, problem is on the receiving end, you can try add mime type and send as dict of 3-element tuples `form_data= {"image": ("image.jpeg", mem_file, "image/jpeg")}`

Comment: Hello @mugiseyebrows I update my code with your suggestion and it worked, thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mugiseyebrows have said I was doing it incorrectly, the form data should be the following

```
form_data= {"image": ("image.jpeg", mem_file, "image/jpeg")}
```

This way the mime type is sent and I was able to send my image throw python request using form-data request

The hole code became the following

```
image = Process().mandelbrot(width, height, max_iter)

mem_file = BytesIO()
image.save(mem_file, "PNG", quality=100)
mem_file.seek(0)
        
id = 'mandelbrot'+str(uuid.uuid4().hex)

requests.post(url='http://database:5000/images', files={'image': ('file.PNG', mem_file, 'image/png')}, params={'id': id})
```